# How show scrollbar only with hover? (support mobile)

Tags: html, css, youtube, scrollbar

I faced with interesting design problem.
I need to make scrollbar as at *youtube* menu (left menu):
Default scrollbar hidden, but with :hover show scrollbar.

I use **overflow: hidden** and  **overflow: auto** ( for :hover).
But for mobile devices don't work for this method.

I search solution and find several interesting way:
https://codepen.io/kizu/pen/OyzGXY

```css
.scrollbox {
  width: 10em;
  height: 10em;
  overflow: auto;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.scrollbox-content,
.scrollbox:hover,
.scrollbox:focus {
  visibility: visible;
}

.scrollbox_delayed {
  transition: visibility 0.2s;
}
.scrollbox_delayed:hover {
  transition: visibility 0s 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<h2>Hover it</h2>
<div class="scrollbox" tabindex="0">
  <div class="scrollbox-content">Hover me! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere velit, repellat voluptas ipsa impedit fugiat voluptatibus. Facilis deleniti, nihil voluptate perspiciatis iure adipisci magni, nisi suscipit aliquam, quam, et excepturi! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere velit, repellat voluptas ipsa impedit fugiat voluptatibus. Facilis deleniti, nihil voluptate perspiciatis iure adipisci magni, nisi suscipit aliquam, quam, et excepturi!</div>
</div>

<h2>With delay</h2>
<div class="scrollbox scrollbox_delayed" tabindex="0">
  <div class="scrollbox-content">Hover me! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere velit, repellat voluptas ipsa impedit fugiat voluptatibus. Facilis deleniti, nihil voluptate perspiciatis iure adipisci magni, nisi suscipit aliquam, quam, et excepturi! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere velit, repellat voluptas ipsa impedit fugiat voluptatibus. Facilis deleniti, nihil voluptate perspiciatis iure adipisci magni, nisi suscipit aliquam, quam, et excepturi!</div>
</div>
```

But I have not know height of wrapper and this solution don't work for me.

Whether there is a working way to make something similar without JS use?
If is not present, then what simplest solution for JS?
(i find example by JS-library: https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ScrollbarVisibility/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Scrollbar rendering is very inconsistent across browsers. On Mac, for example, it does the behavior you describe, by default, if using webkit.

If you want something working across all devices, you should rely on a JS solution.

But I would advice to really think about the use-case behind this, as, as a general rule of thumb, anyone messing with the user's scrollbar has a poorly designed interface to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution to my problem.
This proved to be the obvious method: media query. I set the media query (:hover) for large  devices (PC). And for small devices, the scroll is always shown.

Of course, this solution may not be suitable for everyone, but for me it turned out to be a good solution.

For a universal solution is suitable JS (as Edouard Reinach said).